# No output in terminal running bash script from Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm trying to run a bash script that runs update and upgrade for me in the terminal window from a Python script, using:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['bash', '/home/pi/updatescript.sh'])
```

When I run the python script I see no output in the terminal window like I would if the script were run from there using ./. Is this normal? Or am I doing something wrong?

I tried a few other scripts that I have that use xdotool and they didn't seem to run like they do from terminal either so I am a bit confused.

Comment: you need `check_output` all this will do is return a status code

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: Also if it's an executable script, why call bash? Just call the script.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if it was running as nothing seemed to happen when I called it and so wanted to see it execute in terminal is all. Check output seems to do the job. Thanks for your help gents.